# Layers in interface builder (camerra view is on top :( )

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

Hello I have following hierarchy in my ViewController. The problem is that view (camera output) is on top and I cannot see the buttons. Is there way how to change order of layers in interface builder or by code? (I need buttons on top of course). Thank you

Hierarchy: (cannot put here image due to reputation so pls check link) http://postimg.org/image/tjrj1bx1l/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way may to be take those two buttons and put them into a separate "buttons" view and create another "camera" view below them and add your camera controller to that view via an IBOutlet as opposed to adding the camera to the main view.

If you are adding you camera to the view via code, it is going to place it on top of the other items in your view by default.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not exactly clear from your screenshot what you’re trying to do, but if I understand you correctly, you should be able to drag the views in the Interface Builder sidebar to change their stacking order or whether or not they are nested as subviews.